# Using CASE in PostgreSQL to search for each values in column and return the output with filter

Tags: postgresql

**There is a column with different values like below :**

```
Ava avtar 18.1.100-33_HF305143

app agent 19.9.0.99 (root-2021-323)

BOOST:1.3.0.0-12345 FUSE:2.9.4 ora_dw05_plm10

BOOST:1.3.0.0-12345 FUSE:2.9.4 tar

BOOST:1.3.0.0-12345 FUSE:2.9.4 scp

BOOST:1.3.0.0-12345 FUSE:2.9.7 /usr/pgsql-10/bin/pg_dump

BOOST:1.3.0.1-12345 CBFS 6.1 CVMountd.exe

PP-19.9.0-13-18087

______ ddrmaint 7.5.0-183

________ app agent 4.5.0.0 (52)
```

**In the output when I query using select, I should get as below after filter the column :**

```
Ava avtar 18.1.100

app agent 19.9.0.99

BOOST:1.3.0.0-12345 FUSE:2.9.4

BOOST:1.3.0.0-12345 FUSE:2.9.4

BOOST:1.3.0.0-12345 FUSE:2.9.4

BOOST:1.3.0.0-12345 FUSE:2.9.7

BOOST:1.3.0.1-12345 CBFS 6.1

PP-19.9.0-13

______ ddrmaint 7.5.0

________ app agent 4.5.0.0
```

**I'm trying to use select with CASE for this and not going forward. Please let me know the solution for the same.**

```sql
select
CASE
WHEN 'PP-19.9.0-13-18087' ~ 'PP' THEN split_part('PP-19.9.0-13-18087', '-', 1)
WHEN 'BOOST:1.3.0.0-12345 FUSE:2.9.4 scp' ~ 'BOOST' THEN split_part('BOOST:1.3.0.0-12345 FUSE:2.9.4 scp', ':', 1)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using various tools:split_part, substr, left, reverse.

> ```
> create table t ( value varchar(100));
> insert into t values
> ('Ava avtar 18.1.100-33_HF305143'),
> ('app agent 19.9.0.99 (root-2021-323)'),
> ('BOOST:1.3.0.0-12345 FUSE:2.9.4 ora_dw05_plm10'),
> ('BOOST:1.3.0.0-12345 FUSE:2.9.4 tar'),
> ('BOOST:1.3.0.0-12345 FUSE:2.9.4 scp'),
> ('BOOST:1.3.0.0-12345 FUSE:2.9.7 /usr/pgsql-10/bin/pg_dump'),
> ('BOOST:1.3.0.1-12345 CBFS 6.1 CVMountd.exe'),
> ('PP-19.9.0-13-18087'),
> ('______ ddrmaint 7.5.0-183'),
> ('________ app agent 4.5.0.0 (52)');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

10 rows affected

> 

> ```
> select
>   value,
>   length(value),
>   case left(value,2)
>     when 'Av' then split_part(value, '-', 1)
>     when 'ap' then split_part(value, '(', 1)
>     when 'BO' then case
>       when value ~ 'BOOST:1(\.\d)+ FUSE' then left(value,30)
>       else left(value,28)
>       end
>     when 'PP' then reverse(substr(reverse(value),strpos(reverse(value),'-')+1,length(value)))
>     when '__' then case
>       when value ~ 'ddrmaint' then left(value,21)
>       else left(value,26)
>       end
>     else value 
>   end as processed_value
> from t
> ```

> ```
> value                                                    | length | processed_value             
> :------------------------------------------------------- | -----: | :---------------------------
> Ava avtar 18.1.100-33_HF305143                           |     30 | Ava avtar 18.1.100          
> app agent 19.9.0.99 (root-2021-323)                      |     35 | app agent 19.9.0.99         
> BOOST:1.3.0.0-12345 FUSE:2.9.4 ora_dw05_plm10            |     45 | BOOST:1.3.0.0-12345 FUSE:2.9
> BOOST:1.3.0.0-12345 FUSE:2.9.4 tar                       |     34 | BOOST:1.3.0.0-12345 FUSE:2.9
> BOOST:1.3.0.0-12345 FUSE:2.9.4 scp                       |     34 | BOOST:1.3.0.0-12345 FUSE:2.9
> BOOST:1.3.0.0-12345 FUSE:2.9.7 /usr/pgsql-10/bin/pg_dump |     56 | BOOST:1.3.0.0-12345 FUSE:2.9
> BOOST:1.3.0.1-12345 CBFS 6.1 CVMountd.exe                |     41 | BOOST:1.3.0.1-12345 CBFS 6.1
> PP-19.9.0-13-18087                                       |     18 | PP-19.9.0-13                
> ______ ddrmaint 7.5.0-183                                |     25 | ______ ddrmaint 7.5.0       
> ________ app agent 4.5.0.0 (52)                          |     31 | ________ app agent 4.5.0.0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=b714ecd8ddfa2ff807b2e6a7ae31efb8)